# Can I use the results of a query as criteria for the initial pull of a second query in Excel Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I am using Microsoft Excel's Power Query to pull information directly from two separate data sources (IBM DB2 and Teradata) and merge them together in an Excel worksheet. The results of the first query, from DB2, are only around 300 rows, and I want to return data from the Teradata table only where it matches those 300 rows (a left join). The Teradata table is very large (more than 5 million). When I build my query in Excel's Power Query, it wants to pull the entire Teradata table first before joining it with the 300 criteria rows, and due to the size of the Teradata table, it fails.

Is there a way for me to set it up so that the initial query pull in Power Query from the Teradata table incorporates the results of the first query, so that it will process and pull back the matching information?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a query like that, with two different systems as the data sources, all the data will have to be pulled into Excel so that Power Query can work a join or a filter.

With SQL data sources, Power Query can use query folding to create a Select statement that incorporates filters and joins, but that can not be applied when the data is on two totally separate systems. In that case, Excel is the tool that performs the selection, and in order to do that, all the data has to be in Excel first.

If that is too big for Excel to handle, you could try Power BI and see if that makes a difference when the data is refreshed through a data gateway.

Comment: Thank you teylyn. It wouldn't be possible for Excel to have an SQL statement that has a WHERE clause that references a table outside of the data source, would it? I had been running this merging of IBM and Teradata information sources through Tableau, but was looking for a better/more direct way to generate the data. I'll see what I can do with Power BI though.